# How to add timestamp to pipe output?

Tags: perl, bash, pipe

I need to add a timestamp in front of the output of a long-executing command (a "tcpdump", in my use-case...).

It - very simplified - looks like this one:

```
(echo A1; sleep 3; echo B2) | perl -MPOSIX -pe 'print strftime "%T ", localtime $^T; s/\d//'
```

which gives this kind of output:

```
16:10:24 A
16:10:24 B
```

i.e.: perl's localtime is (obviously) called when perl is invoked.

Instead I need this kind of result:

```
16:10:24 A
16:10:27 B
```

i.e.: time stamp should be relative to the input's generation time...

Any smart (or no so smart :-) solution?

Comment: have you tried to remove `$^T`?

Comment: Great! That's it! I feel ashamed... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `$^T` from your Perl command. That way, you will use the current time instead of the process start time. See the [docs for `$^T`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5eT).

However, a more elegant formulation with Perl would be:

```
... | perl -MPOSIX -ne's/\d//; print strftime("%T ", localtime), $_'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pipe the output to:

```
awk '{ print strftime("%T"), $0; }'
```

Example:

```
while : ; do echo hey; sleep 1; done | awk '{ print strftime("%T"), $0; }'
20:49:58 hey
20:49:59 hey
20:50:00 hey
20:50:01 hey
20:50:02 hey
20:50:03 hey
20:50:04 hey
20:50:05 hey
```

Alternatively, you could use [`ts`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
ts '%T'
```

Comment: @MarcoS The full command would be: `your_command | awk '{ print strftime("%T"), $0; }'`

Comment: Sorry but

    (echo A; sleep 3; echo B) | perl -pe 's/rubbish//' | awk '{ print strftime("%T"), $0; }'

works doesn't change things...

Comment: @MarcoS You need to tell perl to stop buffering.  Say `(echo A; sleep 3; echo B) | perl -pe '$|++; s/rubbish//' | awk '{ print strftime("%T"), $0; }'`

Comment: @MarcoS That's ok.  Makes sense as the answer pointed out the problem with your code instead of providing an alternate solution.

Comment: Please add the info that strftime only works with gawk or mawk >1.3.4 (not sure about the last number), certainly not on all awks.

Answer (score 1):

```
(echo A1; sleep 3; echo B2) | perl -MPOSIX -pe 'print strftime "%T ", localtime; s/\d//'
```

Works excellent for me. Why you added `$^T` there?

Answer (score 0):

on Linux, you can use `tcpdump -tttt` to print the timestamp before each output line.

```
# tcpdump -tttt -c 1 2>/dev/null
2013-12-13 23:42:12.044426 IP 10.0.2.15.ssh > 10.0.2.2.53466: Flags [P.], seq 464388005:464388121, ack 16648998, win 65535, length 116
```

If your tcpdump doesn't have the -tttt option, you should use awk from devnull